# Using a math font matching San Serif Font

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How can I match the font of an equation to a Sans Serif font? I am using the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}


\usepackage[scaled, mono=false]{libertine} 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section*{Sans Serif Font along with equation and formula}

\noindent How can I put my equation between dollar signs, e.g., \verb|$E=mc^2$|, and get an output which matches a Sans Serif font? 

\noindent Here is the result of \verb|$E=mc^2$|: $E=mc^2$

\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: well, not all fonts have a math support. I think that Euler matches Libertine reasonably: add `\usepackage{eulervm}` into your preamble and see whether you like it or not.

Comment: Is it just me who reads the title as *my kingdom for a horse*? Free association is weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`sansmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) package.

> The package is designed to offer sans-serif mathematics in the absence of proper sans maths fonts.
>
> The package’s name could be misconstrued: there was an ambition to do the job for “non-standard” sans fonts (as indicated by the value of `\sfdefault`), but the only good results have been with Computer Modern and cmss.

To use the package, add `\usepackage{sansmath}` to your preamble, and then use the `\sansmath` command in any maths environment when you want to switch to a sans-serif font.

If you want this applied to every maths environment in your document, you can use `\sansmath` in your document preamble.

Comment: It did not work for me. I get the same result, no change.

Comment: However, that's a poor man's solution...

Comment: @tohecz: I liked the look of the `sansmath`'s result more than `\usepackage{eulervm}` after I got `sansmath` to work by using `\sansmath{$E=mc^2$}` but you know `sansmath` is kind of inconvenient as I have to put in in front of all the equations. The solution you suggested is very convenient but the look is different.

Comment: @A2009 I've edited my answer to show you how to avoid having to put `\sansmath` in front of every equation.

Comment: Unfortunately,`\everymath{\sansmath}` does not work for me. It has no effect unless I use `\sansmath{$E=mc^2$}`.

Comment: @A2009 Answer updated so that it actually works.

Comment: @A2009, the documentation _says_ that `\everymath{\sansmath}` doesn't work.  i've saved typing by putting `\sansmath` immediately _after_ `\begin{document}` (only); really no need for the command for every equation, which you say you needed.